# What is a reference value in Java and why does it change?

Tags: java, arrays, pointers

Coming from Languages without a GC (C/C++/Rust..) i am wondering what exactly is happening if an array is reallocated.

if we're in a c++ like language(pseudo code), this is considered bad:

```
Obj *x = xarr[2];
xarr.push(new Obj(12));
do_with(x);
```

running example in c++ http://ideone.com/qk7vcj

after the push, x may point to freed memory due to reallocation of xarr.

x is basically just a pointer sized integer storing the memory address of xarr[2].

if i do the same in java. this is working just fine and i am wondering why?

```
List<OBJ> list = new ArrayList<>();    
list.add(new OBJ());
list.add(new OBJ());
list.add(new OBJ());

OBJ x = list.get(2);
for (int idx = 0; idx < 1000000; idx++) {
    list.add(new OBJ());    
}
do_it(x);
```

what exactly is x and how and why is the memory address of x changed after  the array is seemingly reallocated?

obviously java is not deepcopying the array because x2 could not change x like in this code as you can see, the address of x is changing, too.

```
private static class OBJ {
    int one;
    String two;

    public OBJ() {
        this.one = 1;
        this.two = "two";
    }
}

public static void do_it(OBJ o) {
    System.out.println("o.two is: " + o.two); 
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    List<OBJ> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new OBJ());
    list.add(new OBJ());
    list.add(new OBJ());

    OBJ x = list.get(2);

    printAddresses("Address x", x);

    for (int idx = 0; idx < 1000000; idx++) {
        list.add(new OBJ());    
    }

    OBJ x2 = list.get(2);
    x2.two = "haha";

    printAddresses("Address x", x);

    do_it(x);

}
```

should not print out this

```
Address x: 0x525554440
Address x: 0x550882b80
o.two is: haha
```

full working example can be found here http://ideone.com/P3j6xF

so that begs the question how is the address of x changed after the reallocation of the list. And what exactly is the so called "reference"? I thought the so called "reference" in Java is just an ordinary pointer with something like autodereference and no pointer arithmetic because in Java everything is passed by value and not by reference. this is clearly evident in this code http://ideone.com/k4Ijq0

```
public static void test1(OBJ o) {
    o.one = 2;
}

public static void test2(OBJ o) {
    o = new OBJ();
    o.two = "no reference";
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    OBJ x = new OBJ();
    test1(x);
    test2(x);

    System.out.println("x.one: " + x.one + " x.two: " + x.two);
}
```

printing out

```
x.one: 2 x.two: two
```

so it seems like x is behaving like a pointer but somehow java is redirecting it if necessary. How does this work? The term "reference" is extra confusing, why is it called like that?

Comment: Also, [What is the difference between a variable, object, and reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010172/what-is-the-difference-between-a-variable-object-and-reference)

Comment: @ Sotirios Delimanolis this does not really address my problem.

Comment: Please clarify then. What do you mean by _bend that reference_?

Comment: _"after the push, x may point to freed memory due to reallocation of xarr."_ I think you made a mistake here? That could happen in the case of ```std::list<OBJ>``` but not ```std::list<OBJ *>```.

Comment: It seems like the JVM just likes to move things around, even if you create a separate list and iterate over that instead, the memory address still changes.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis as written in the example x has a new address in memory after an element is added to the list. (printAddresses)

Comment: @Jorn Vernee i've added a running c++ example for clarification. Thx for asking to clarify the situation, pseudo code is not always the best and real code can explain things easier.

Comment: Oh, you're confused about the `Unsafe` output. That's what happens when you play with `Unsafe`. While you were creating and adding new objects to your list, the JVM had to perform a garbage collection cycle and likely moved your object. Create fewer objects and you'll see the object will remain in the same location. The JVM updates these references as needed during GC. This should be transparent to the programmer and so isn't exposed (unless you choose to play with `Unsafe`).

Comment: If you can reword your question to ask specifically about that, I'll reopen. Right now, a large part of it is not relevant to _that_ question.

Comment: An `ArrayList` in Java doesn't hold objects.  It holds *references to* objects that are allocated separately.  Even if the array gets reallocated, the objects are unaffected.  The closest equivalent in C++ would be `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>`.

Comment: @Wyzard sry but your example with shared_ptr is not right. http://ideone.com/vnPn1n this behaves exactly like my other example code in the post.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis i am not confused about the Unsafe. I am confused about the behavior of the JVM and why and how it behaves so differently like other languages i know. I know that an array gets - eventually - reallocated and the hole purpose of adding lots of objects was to enforce reallocation for demonstration. Sry i don't know how to reword my question cuz i don't know whats going on. if i could exactly describe what i don't understand i don't need to ask in the first place. i just presented the behavior as good as i could and ask why and how java behaves like this.

Comment: You can not use ```auto&``` with ```shared_ptr```, you actually have to copy it for the behaviour to be java-like. ---> [ideone](http://ideone.com/bOUTeP)

Comment: @JornVernee would you be so kind and give an example that behaves like my Jave example http://ideone.com/P3j6xF ?

Comment: I did in my updated comment, the one thing I can't model, is the GC moving objects around.

Comment: [The answers to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88852/does-the-java-vm-move-objects-in-memory-and-if-so-how) <--- Should also give any idea as to why the object is moved.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake earlier. Here is a better example: [Link](http://ideone.com/IwDPOH)

Answer (score 1):

The [Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.4) states

> There are three kinds of reference types: class types, array types,
>   and interface types. **Their values are references to dynamically
>   created class instances, arrays, or class instances or arrays that
>   implement interfaces, respectively.**

Similarly, the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1) states

> The **reference values (often just references) are pointers** to these
>   objects, and a special null reference, which refers to no object.

In other words, values for reference types are (more or less) the address of a corresponding object. This is obviously abstracted away from you, the Java developer. You never need to know where an object is in memory because you don't manage memory. The JVM does that.

When you do this

```
OBJ x = new OBJ();
```

or get the reference value some other way

```
OBJ x = list.get(2);
```

The variable `x` simply holds that reference value, which points to the actual object (or potentially the `null`reference).

Java is a garbage collected language. [Modern garbage collection algorithms use generational and copying strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88852/does-the-java-vm-move-objects-in-memory-and-if-so-how). That is, they'll move around objects between generations as they decide how long-lived those objects are. That move is a copy and clear. The GC will go through a dedicated area, copy all live objects to another area and mark the original as free memory.

This is obviously problematic for our previously mentioned `x` variable. If it was pointing to a live object in memory and that memory was "cleared", we're setting ourselves up for problems. The GC therefore has to go through all the variables (instance variables, local variables, array elements) that stored the location of a moved object and update them before allowing the program to proceed (done during Stop The World collections).

This is what you see with your `Unsafe` code.

```
OBJ x = list.get(2);
printAddresses("Address x", x);
```

The object referenced by the value stored in `x` is in a certain location in memory when you first invoke `printAddresses`. After generating a bunch of new objects, triggering the garbage collector, the object is moved to a new location and all references to it are updated (the value in `x`, the value in the `ArrayList`'s underlying array). If you had more memory (or created fewer objects), this would not have occurred (yet).

> How does Array reallocation work in Java?

This has nothing to do with the array, really. The `ArrayList` object contains an array field (named `elementData` which references an array object. For example

```
elementData = 0x4000
```

and that object, internally, has references to other objects (array elements are variables).

```
elementData[0] = 0x6720
elementData[1] = 0x6808
elementData[2] = 0x4393
elementData[3] = 0x7121
elementData[4] = 0x2425
elementData[5] = 0x4867
elementData[6] = 0x976
elementData[7] = 0x1082
elementData[8] = 0x4160
elementData[9] = 0x1850
```

When you hit that element limit and `ArrayList` has to reallocate the array, it simply copies over all those reference values to a new array.

```
elementData = 0x8900;
elementData[0] = 0x6720 (same as above)
elementData[1] = 0x6808
elementData[2] = 0x4393
elementData[3] = 0x7121
elementData[4] = 0x2425
elementData[5] = 0x4867
elementData[6] = 0x976
elementData[7] = 0x1082
elementData[8] = 0x4160
elementData[9] = 0x1850
elementData[10] = 0x0000 (something for null)
...
elementData[newLength-1] = 0x0000
```

assuming of course that none of these objects were moved during a garbage collection cycle. If they had, the GC would've updated the array variables as well.

**Again, though, as a Java developer, you shouldn't need to care about any of this.** It'll very rarely come in handy when writing Java code. You never have access to the actual reference value directly (except when playing with `Unsafe`).

Answer (score 0):

The reallocation of the list doesn't change the value of `x`. In Java, `x` will contain a reference to the created object. If the array backing the list is reallocated, then `x` is still a reference to the same object.

What you're seeing is the addresses of objects changing because of the garbage collector. You can see the same results where `x` is not in the list at all:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<OBJ> list = new ArrayList<>(10000000);

    OBJ x = new OBJ();

    printAddresses("Address x", x);

    for (int idx = 0; idx < 1000000; idx++) {
        list.add(new OBJ());
    }

    printAddresses("Address x", x);
}
```

Output:

```
Address x: 0x710b05580
Address x: 0x54d5a19c0
```

Objects can be moved around in memory as the garbage collector does its work. When this happens, then any addresses that need to be changed are updated at the same time.

Also, in c++, your value of `x` is a reference to an item within the list, so if the list is reallocated this reference becomes invalid. In Java `x` is a copy of an item in the list so it doesn't matter if the list is reallocated. It's not possible to have a reference to an element in Java.

`List<OBJ>` in Java is really a list of references to objects. These objects exist independently of the list. You can take a copy of one of these references to get a new reference to the same object.